# Error when deploying my application in tomcat with eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I have an eclipse dynamic web  project. I have an Tomcat v7.0 on which I am deploying my application. When I start my tomcat server it gives following error.

```
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class 
        com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
        java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
```

I understand that it is trying to read the JSF configuration file. I don't have the jsf-api.jar and jsf-impl.jar in my lib. I don't want to have it as it is not a JSF project.

From where is it trying to read it? And how do I resolve it? I have searched, however most forums end in saying 'issue resolved' without any explanation or steps to resolution.

Comment: Yes, the tomcat is saying it does. But from where Tomcat is asking for these ? I have not modified tomcat installation configuration. So it must be from eclipse....and that is what I want to understand.

Comment: Also I did not had this problem a couple of days back.

Comment: You changed something.  Change it back.  It's not worth donating more time to somebody who only accepts on 40% of their questions.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If your project doesn't require JSF, is Tomcat saying that it does?  Try putting those JARs in the Tomcat /lib.

Or, better yet, just tell Eclipse where they are temporarily.  You don't need to have them in your Tomcat or WAR file that way.  It'll leave you with the problem of how to resolve it when you're not using Eclipse, but it'll be a step along the road.

Comment: Thanks....but my concern is why should i worry about those if i am not using those. why is eclipse demanding those. I want to understand it.

Comment: Eclipse can be a bit bloated.  I'd recommend creating a WAR file for your app without Eclipse and seeing if that deploys successfully.  If it does, then you know that it's just part of the price you pay for using Eclipse.  If you get tired of it, step up to IntelliJ.

Comment: `Nov 4, 2012 9:24:07 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Nov 4, 2012 9:24:07 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/ttmm-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] startup failed due to previous errors`

Comment: Jaysus, leave Maven out of it, too.  Just create a WAR file, put it in the apps directory, and start Tomcat.  Too much machinery to do something simple.  This is why I hate Maven and Eclipse.  There are too many layers in the way that obscure what's going on.